# VSCode won't bind client-side breakpoints for nextjs (9.5.2)

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, next.js, vscode-debugger

In one of the recent updates to nextjs, client-side chrome debugging in vscode seems to have broken. When I launch the following configuration, none of my breakpoints are ever bound:

```
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Chrome on localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/pathto/myapp"
        },
```

Note that I am using the `Debugger for Chrome (v4.12.10)` extension on `VSCode (v1.48.1)` and I am debugging the client side javascript served by `nextjs (v9.5.2)` running in Chrome, not the nextjs node process.

Does anyone know what's changed and how to get the debugger to bind breakpoints again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Previously, vscode would (by default) use the following source map paths to interpret source maps served by webpack:

```
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///*": "*",
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
                "meteor://app/*": "${webRoot}/*"
            }
```

If you look in `sources` in chrome devtools, though, you can find the source maps under the mysterious `_N_E` path (the orange folders refer to sources with source maps).

[image]

It seems like in a recent update, in preparation for webpack 5, the nextjs team changed the path at which source maps are served: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/15955

So this means that none of the default source map path overrides are resolving correctly.

Adding `"webpack://_N_E/*": "${webRoot}/*"` as an override fixed this issue!

Also, note the `//` double slash instead of the previous `///` triple slashes.

Here's my working launch config (put this under `configurations` in `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Chrome on localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/pathto/myapp",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack://_N_E/*": "${webRoot}/*"
            }
        },
```

Don't forget to change /pathto/myapp to the path of your app root in your repository. This could also end in `/src` if you're using that. Or remove it entirely if you're using `nextjs` out of the box!

Hope this helps someone! Sure left me scratching my head in confusion...

Edit:

I actually opened an issue over at `nextjs` pointing out some problems with their documentation. If many other people have this problem, I suggest making a note there so that the nextjs team become aware of it!

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16442

Comment: "[...]nextjs is mostly a black box to me, and I am blissfully unaware." +1 Thank you for helping me out on this one. The documentation is indeed, very sparse on that topic

Comment: As of January 11, 2023, I don't seem to need the sourceMapPathOverrides. My mistake came from trying to debug server components in VSCode only talking to my client. Once I inadvertently placed a breakpoint in a component that had 'use client', my breakpoint bound.